# Decimal to ASCII Conversion

Tags: c#, wpf, type-conversion

how can i convert decimal value to AScii , i have tried with

```
var charStrs = Convert.ToString(receivedEvent.tagData.can_Msg.data[3]) +
               Convert.ToString(receivedEvent.tagData.can_Msg.data[4]) + 
               Convert.ToString(receivedEvent.tagData.can_Msg.data[5]) + 
               Convert.ToString(receivedEvent.tagData.can_Msg.data[6]) + 
               Convert.ToString(receivedEvent.tagData.can_Msg.data[7]);
var asStr = String.Concat(charStrs.Select(cs => (char)Int32.Parse(cs, NumberStyles.HexNumber)));
```

i know that my decimal number = 56 49 50 48 48 48 53 56 50 56 and when converting it to ascii i will get 8120005828;but i get error in NumberStyles.HexNumber its seems it does not work on wpf ?

Comment: This question is really unclear - partly because of the horrible code layout, and partly because you haven't really explained clearly what you're trying to achieve. Sample input and expected output, and well-formatted code omitting irrelevant bits would be useful.

Comment: @user2933082 You've just been Skeet'd.

Comment: I'm still wondering what in the world does this have to do with WPF.

Comment: @HighCore i mean that NumberStyles.HexNumber is not supported in WPF unlike windowform...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not really sure what values are in `data[3]`, etc. but with values from http://www.asciitable.com/

```
int[] values = { 56, 49, 50, 48, 48, 48, 53, 56, 50, 56 };
char[] chars = values.Select(x => (char)x).ToArray();
string str = new string(chars);
Console.WriteLine(str); // "8120005828"
```

Part of your problem might be that those are decimal numbers, but you're trying to parse them as hex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
data[0] = ((char)(Int32.Parse(data[0], NumberStyles.HexNumber))).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(data.Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + (char)(Int32.Parse(s2, NumberStyles.HexNumber))) );
```

This will work for your scenario