# How to convert Decimal to ASCII in c#.net?

Tags: c#, decimal, ascii

Can anyone help me on how to convert decimal to ASCII using C#.net?

When I input a decimal into the textbox1, after clicking the CONVERT button then the result will display in textbox2. My problem is the code on how to convert decimal to ASCII. How to do this?

Comment: Did you look at [`System.Text.Encoding.ASCII`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.Encoding_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `10m.ToString()` will produce string with only ASCII characters... But it is probably not what you are looking for - please clarify what you expect as input/output.

Comment: You can not convert decimal to ASCII, if decimal looks like 235.21. You can do it with int, but not with decimal. What is your goal to split the decimal to two parts after the '.' and before it and show the ASCII symbols of the both of parts ?

Comment: @ja72 how to do that?

Comment: @mybirthname Ok. Thanks for the info! How about Hex to ASCII? Is there any way?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov can you show me how to do that? The 10m.ToString()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple solution I found on the net. See if it works for you. 65 being the ASCII character.

```
char c = Convert.ToChar(65);
string d = c.ToString();
```

Source: http://forums.asp.net/t/1827433.aspx?Converting+decimal+value+to+equivalent+ASCII+character+in+c+

Another source: [Decimal to ASCII Convertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985544/decimal-to-ascii-convertion)

Comment: It get's error when I ask an input to the user, the program run when **.ToChar(65)** is fix.

Comment: What is the error that you're seeing? What do you mean .ToChar(65) is fix?

Comment: I made a program that will ask user an input, char c = Convert.ToChar(65); is a fix code because you were basically put **65** in the codes, not an input made by the user. Actually, when i used this code **char c = Convert.ToChar(65);** there's no error, error occured when i change **65** into a string variable which holds the input of the user.

Comment: 65 is an ASCII number that stands for A. Take a look at [the ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for more information.

As for your error, you're giving it the wrong input. The ToChar() method takes a single character. What is your input? Is it a string or an array of decimals?

Answer (score 1):

Is ASCII a requirement? Normally UTF-8 should be used when sending a string to another app.

```
var utf8 = Encoding.Utf8.GetBytes(myDecimal.ToString());
```

However, if you just want to convert a `decimal` to a string do

```
var s = myDecimal.ToString();
```

Comment: My program must ask a decimal/hex input by the user then convert it to ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

For example you have a Textbox and a Button
Textbox name is txtInput.

```
//Converting Decimal to ASCII
 MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToByte( txtInput.Text )).ToString());

    //Convertşng ASCII to Decimal
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToChar( txtInput.Text )).ToString());
```